# (Algorithm) Find if two unsorted arrays have any common elements in O(n) time without sorting?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

We have two unsorted arrays and each array has a length of n. These arrays contain random integers in the range of 0-n<sup>100</sup>. How to find if these two arrays have any common elements in O(n)/linear time? Sorting is not allowed.

Comment: Smells like homework.  If it is, mark it as such.

Comment: So the answer is just yes/no, yes if they have *any* elements in common, no otherwise?

Comment: How about storage? O(n)?

Comment: Storage is not important. And you are right, this is a yes/no question.

Comment: IMO, The current accepted answer by meriton is useless. (Apologies to meriton).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not defined the model of computation. Assuming you can only read O(1) bits in O(1) time (anything else would be a rather exotic model of computation), there can be no algorithm solving the problem in O(n) worst case time complexity.

Proof Sketch:
Each number in the input takes O(log(n ^ 100)) = O(100 log n) = O(log n) bits. The entire input therefore O(n log n) bits, which can not be read in O(n) time. Any O(n) algorithm can therefore not read the entire input, and hence not react if these bits matter.

Comment: This question can be solved in O(n) time using radix sort or similar sorting algorithms. But the problem here is that sorting is not allowed.

Comment: @Omerta: It cannot be solved in O(n) worst case even with radix sorting unless you use some unusual computational model.

Comment: Radix sort is O(kn) where n is the count of numbers, and k the length of the numbers. If k is constant, that is O(n), but k is O(log n) here ...

Comment: -1: This is defeating the spirit of the question. Besides, Word RAM Model is not that exotic. In fact, most algorithm time complexity analyses implicitly use that when unspecified: O(1) time array accesses, O(1) addition of two integers which fit in a register etc.

Comment: Both "registers" and "words" have fixed size, regardless of n. Here, the numbers get longer as n increases, making it impossible to store them in a constant number of "words" or "registers".

Comment: @meriton: IF you can store n in a register, that is all you need. Besides, if you really want to use your model, your interpretation of the question is wrong! Linear time in your case is O(nlogn), as the size of the input is O(nlogn)... O(n) will be sublinear. So you really haven't answered the question.

Comment: The question does not define n as the length of the input but as the count of numbers in the input. And it asks for O(n) time.

Comment: @meriton: It also says O(n)/_Linear_ time. It is obvious the intent here is linear time. You do agree linear time means linear in length of input, which in your model is Theta(nlogn)?

Comment: This is a wrong answer in RAM computation model, for more information see this post: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-can-we-assume-comparison-addition-between-numbers-is-o1

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: I disagree; in fact, my definition of "O(1) bits in O(1) time" is consistent with what the accepted answer to the linked question calls "the 21st-century standard model of computation: the integer RAM".  However, the question defines `n` as the "length" of an input array, not the number of memory words it occupies. You can not store 2n numbers with 100 log n digits in n memory words.

Answer (score 11):

Hashtable will save you. Really, it's like a swiss knife for algorithms.
Just put in it all values from the first array and then check if any value from the second array is present.

Comment: Because we know the maximum size of the values we can prove O(n) storage. EDIT: Whoops, that is O(n^2) storage. EDIT2: Whoops again, it is O(n).

Comment: Using hashtable is O(nlog n).

Comment: @GregS The interesting thing is, we don't even need to store values themselves in the hashtable. We can store only hashes (which will be much smaller) and pointers to numbers.

Comment: @Neil: Searches are usually O(1), building is O(n).

Comment: While this is a good aproach in practice, it doesn't achieve O(n) *worst case* performance. First because a hashtable lookup is O(n) in the worst case (bad hash function, and for every hash function, there is an input with many hash collisions), and second because you implicitly assume the hash function can be computed in constant time, even though the number of bits used to hold an number is not constant.

Comment: Searches are O(1) ideally, though with that many numbers, I doubt that it's anything close to that efficiency without an extremely large hash table.  It's probably closer to O(log n), and searching n values in this fashion you get O(nlog n).

Comment: @meriton The second argument is very much valid, but it can be applied to any solution: storing n numbers will take O(n^2) space according to problem definition. And we have to read those.

Comment: @Neil Believe me, their take time very close to constant with any decent hash function and hastable just 2x or 3x size of data. I used them.

Comment: @Meriton: Agree. @Neil: What do you mean "with that many numbers"? There are *n* of them, it is a variable. You can achieve average case performance of O(1) using O(n) storage, where "average case" means they keys are reasonably nicely distributed.

Comment: @Nikita It's probably the way I'd do it, yet we're talking theoretically.  And in theory, practice and theory are the same, yet in practice, they're completely different things.  You can't label it O(1) unless it is O(1).  Meaning, we'd have to take into account the size of the hash table with respect to n, etc.

Comment: @Neil It is O(1), with provided conditions. There's a simple proof: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable#Performance_analysis  Not to mention, hashtables have nothing to do with logarithms in general.

Comment: @Nikita: O(n log n), if I calculate correctly? log(n^100) = 100 log (n). But yes, unless the model of computation (which the question sadly not defines) can process O(log n) bits in O(1) time, there can be no algorithm meeting all constraints.

Comment: @Nikita: Each entry is at most n^100, which can be stored I think with 100*log(n) storage. So I guess the storage is O(n log n). This is my third answer on this, so nobody should trust it.

Comment: @meriton @GregS My bad, you're absolutely right, the storage is logarithm.

Comment: @Nikita, OP says "Storage is not important".

Comment: Are we making the assumption here that we know how many numbers there will be as input?  If not, then table resizing and collisions will be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Answering Neil:
Since you know at start what is your N (two arrays of size N), you can create a hash with array size of 2*N*some_ratio (for example: some_ratio= 1.5). With this size, almost all simple hash functions will provide you good spread of the entities.

You can also implement find_or_insert to search for existing or insert a new one at the same action, this will reduce the hash function and comparison calls. (c++ stl find_or_insert is not good enough since it doesnt tell you whether the item was there before or not).

Comment: He said storage wasn't an issue.  Hashtable is a compromise between storage and speed of access.  Why should I compromise storage if I don't have to?

Comment: If the values range can fit into RAM memory - then yes, your approach is good, but 32 bit range is 4G range which is considered very large, even today. (4GB Ram are not enough since you need extra memory, so not every computer can run this on RAM). If you take 64 bit range - no doubt you will never have enough memory.

Answer (score 2):

**Linearity Test**

Using Mathematica hash function and arbitrary length integers.

[image]

Tested until **n=2^20**, generating random numbers till (2^20)^100 = (approx 10^602)

Just in case ... the program is:

```
k = {};
For[t = 1, t < 21, t++,
  i = 2^t;
  Clear[a, b];
  Table[a[RandomInteger[i^100]] = 1, {i}];
  b = Table[RandomInteger[i^100], {i}];
  Contains = False;
  AppendTo[k,
   {i, First@Timing@For[j = 2, j <= i, j++,
       Contains = Contains || (NumericQ[a[b[[j]]]]);
       ]}]];
ListLinePlot[k, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"n", "Time(secs)"}]
```

Comment: Hehe, man shows up with a graph and the room gets quiet. Well we knew that the hash table had linear average case performance.

Comment: @GregS The case is for **arbitrary length integers**. We all knew the hash part.

Comment: Evaluating `a[b[j]]` takes O(log n) steps since b[j] contains O(log n) digits. On average, the first duplicate in b occurs at position n/2. And in fact your example likely produces no duplicates between the lists, so you'd have to iterate through the entire list before failure. Sounds like O(n log n) to me no matter what the graph shows.

Comment: @GregS That's why I made the graphics in first place. My bet was not linear. Perhaps we can come to another test that shows your insight?

Answer (score 1):

If storage is not important, then scratch hash table in favor for an array of n in length.  Flag to true when you come across that number in first array.  In pass through second array, if you find any of them to be true, you have your answer.  O(n).

```
Define largeArray(n)
// First pass
for(element i in firstArray)
   largeArray[i] = true;

// Second pass
Define hasFound = false;
for(element i in secondArray)
   if(largeArray[i] == true) 
      hasFound = true;
      break;
```

Comment: Huh? Define the operation "when you come across that number in the first array". This sounds like a linear search.

Comment: Hashtable is not an option as it'll cost you O(n^2) time in the worst case scenario.

Comment: I meant, if you do array[currentNumber] and it's true, it means the same number existed in the first array and therefore you have your solution.  You're not searching all values in the array because the index itself is the number you're searching for.

Comment: The numbers in the input can be as big as n^100. Your array would therefore have to hold n^100 elements. I challenge you to initialize that array in O(n) time.

Comment: For each element e in largeArray, e = false.  It's always O(n) so long as the number of passes I make is constant.

Comment: ... even if the array contains n*n*n*n*n*n*n*n*...*n elements ...?

Comment: You're confusing n's here.  His 'n' is any number whereas my n is the typical Big O notation.  The number of numbers total is n.  If you then want to tell me it's a really big number like k^100, it's always n.  I cycle through all elements once to initialize, even if n is k*k*k*k*k*k*k in size.

Comment: ... by that logic, all algorithms are O(n), you just have to use the right definition of n. What you are overlooking is that n represents the length of the input. You can't choose it because the input determines it. I recommend you read up on O-Notation if you don't believe me; this is clearly outside the scope of this question.

Comment: The reason why it's n is because it's variable.  What makes it O(n) is that it only has one dimension of growth.  In fact that is the case here.  You make three passes and only three passes and you know your answer.  Had it been m passes where m is some unknown number, it'd be O(n*m) or essentially O(n^2).  I suggest you read up on O notation on the contrary.  :)

Comment: @Neil: The point is it your array is O(n log n) in size, not O(n). So it takes O(n log n) just to initialize your array.

Comment: Actually, since the array must hold a bit for every number that could possibly appear in the input, it has size O(n^100). So it takes O(n^100) just to initialize this array.

Comment: "We have two unsorted arrays and each array has a length of n."  It's not n log n nor is it n^100.  I want a bit to tell me if I've seen that number at the given index.  To initialize such an array, I assign each to zero (1 per boolean value).  If I do it n times, I've done it in O(n) time.  Even if it were an integer, normally such considerations are not made, seeing how every algorithm out there would then be multiplied by m where m is the number of bits which represents it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.  Read it please.

Answer (score 1):

Put the elements of the first array in an hash table, and check for existence scanning the second array. This gives you a solution in O(N) average case.

If you want a truly O(N) worst case solution then instead of using an hash table use a linear array in the range 0-n^100. Note that you need to use just a single bit per entry.

Comment: Not wrong, but it takes O(n log n) just to initialize the array.

Comment: How would you initialize that array of size O(n^100) in O(n) time? Your algorithm assumes that all bits in the array are initially 0.

Comment: @GregS: in our theoretical model memory accesses should be O(1), the same for allocations on the heap: O(1) amortized time. So initializing the array with all zeros should just take O(N) time.

Comment: Sorry there was a misunderstanding here. When I say O(N), N is not the n^100 stuff, but with N being the number of elements in the range 0-n^100. Sorry for the imprecision. Now that I look at this the original poster question looks a bit stranger...

Comment: @antirez: What theoretical memory model? None was provided.

Comment: The question does not define the model of computation. However, a model of computation that allows to write O(log n) bits in O(1) time seems weird to me. Does the memory get faster if my input gets larger ...?

Comment: yep sorry I was completely focused on the idea of O(N) different elements, not n^100 elements. Sorry for misreading the original question. Btw the question is odd, as there is no way to achieve this into O(N), as indeed this would require a very odd memory model in which we can allocate zeroed bits in O(log n).

Comment: <shameless plug> ... which is why my answer states there can be no such algorithm</shameless plug> ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)?  It is simple to implement, uses O(n) space and also has a \theta(n) time complexity.

Comment: ... for numbers whose length does not depend on input size. But here, the numbers get bigger as the input grows longer ...

Comment: The question stated, "These arrays contain random integers in the range of 0-n100." So, we know the distribution of the numbers, so counting sort is *an* alternative.  You are correct that if the numbers are sparse, then this sort is a *huge* waste of space.  I was just giving an idea that no one else had given yet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ideas posted till date.We can store the one array integer elements into a hash map .  Maximum number of different integers can be stored in RAM . Hash map will have only unique integer values. Duplicates are ignored.

Here is the implementation in Perl language.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
sub find_common_elements{ # function that prints common elements in two unsorted array
my (@arr1,@array2)=@_; # array elements assumed to be filled and passed as function arguments 

my $hash; # hash map to store value of one array

# runtime to prepare hash map is O(n). 
foreach my $ele ($arr1){
$hash->{$ele}=true; # true here element exists key is integer number and value is true,          duplicate elements will be overwritten

# size of array will fit in memory as duplicate integers are ignored   ( mx size will     be 2 ^( 32) -1 or 2^(64) -1 based on operating system) which can be stored in RAM.
} 
# O(n ) to traverse second array and finding common elements in two array
foreach my $ele2($arr2){
  # search in hash map is O(1), if all integers of array are same then hash map will have         only one entry and still search tim is O(1) 
   if( defined $hash->{$ele}){  
   print "\n $ele is common in both array \n";
   }
  }
 }
```

I hope it helps.