# comparing sorted arrays - nlogn

Tags: c

i have 2 int arrays i need to print all the identical integers in O(nlogn)
the arrays are not sorted and after sorting can be:

```
X [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Y [1,2,8,9]
```

so checking only till the 4 place(the size of the smaller array) is not an option.

what kind of loop\equation do i need to use so it would be nlogn
?
if i will run the for till the last value of the smaller array -will it still be nlogn-
how can i take\reach only the last integer in arraya without running till the end of it?

Comment: i'm helping a friend...i dont remember this stuff

Comment: Is there any limitation to the inputs? I mean will the array contain only small integer values? If that is the case you can look into [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). Also there is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547452/algorithm-find-if-two-unsorted-arrays-have-any-common-elements-in-on-time-wi) question on SO which you can check.

Answer (score 4):

I'm hoping this is enough of a hint...

Once the arrays are sorted, just walk through the arrays 'side-by-side'.  Keep track of the 'current' element for each array (`X` and `Y`). You might do this using an index variable for each array or by using a pointer.  Personally, I'd find it easier to use pointers, but you or your friend may have a different preference.

For each pair of 'current' elements, if the elements match then print the value. Then consider what needs to be done, if anything, to move to the next element of each array (for the cases where the elements don't match as well as for the case where they do match). There are only three cases:

1. `x[cur_x] == y[cur_y]`
2. `x[cur_x] <  y[cur_y]`
3. `y[cur_y] <  x[cur_x]`

so it shouldn't be too difficult to determine what should be done in each case.

Sorting the arrays in an O(n log n) operation.  Walking through the arrays is an O(n) operation, so altogether it's an O(n) + O(n log n) operation, which reduces down to O(n log n). In other words, the overall time complexity of the  operation is determined by the sort operation.

Using a binary search will also work, but it might be a little more complicated - especially to properly handle duplicated elements in the arrays if that's a requirement (and depending on what 'properly' might mean according to the requirements).

Comment: +1... was wondering why didn't anyone else propose this already! Its kinda like the merge function in mergesort. BST seems too much to me

Comment: Actually, the original answer presented a far to complicated 'solution'. Still, all that needs to be done is to walk through the pair of arrays, considering only the current pair of elements and what needs to be done to move (or not move) to the next element of each array. Considering only one pair of elements in each loop iteration makes the loop termination check dead simple.

Comment: can you show what you mean by alk through the arrays? cause if i understadn that n^2

Comment: +1 This is the most natural and easiest way. @Alexxx you walk in parallel, at each step at least one of the array indices is incremented, none is ever decremented, so it's `n+m` steps at worst if `m <= n` are the array lengths, which is O(n). The sorting step before dominates with O(n*log n) complexity.

Answer (score 3):

You can take the smaller array and search each element in the bigger element with binary search

```
for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {     
  binarysearch(arr_small[i], arr_big);
}
```

binary search requires O(log n) time for each search. Total search time for all elements is O(nlogn)

If you dont remember binary search, refer the link: http://en.literateprograms.org/Binary_search_(C)

Comment: that still be nlogn? is there any way to do it in my way after the 2 arrya was sorted using merge sort?

Comment: that is O(nlogn). In fact this way utilizes the sorted arrays as binary search cannot be done in unsorted array

Comment: why you added (arr_small[i], arr_big) to the function? binary search requries bin_search(int key,int *a,int n) ?

Comment: To use this method, the first step has to be "sort one of the arrays." The Q says that the arrays are initially unsorted.

Comment: MERGE SORT + BINARY SEARCH + COMPARTION - IS THAT STILL NLOGN?

Comment: key (element to search) : arr_small[i],  n is the size of array_big.

Comment: O(nlogn) + n * binary search O(log n)  = O(nlogn). what do you mean by compartion?

Comment: so after the merge sorting - i need to take each one of the elements inside the smaller array and using binary search to find it inside the bigger array? and this all merge sort+binary search would all still be nlogn?

Comment: in your code - what is size1? why the loop is not inside the binarysearch function?  binarysearch(arr_small, arr_big);

Comment: Shraddha, can you please show how the binarysearch needs to look like?

Comment: i took 2 diffrent integer arrays.
i saved their sizes and checked who is bigger or smaller.
i sorted each one of the arrays using merge sort
and called a binary search function to search each one of the smallest array inside the bigger array.

is that nlogn
?

Comment: how i can rid of the duplicates from the smaller array?

Answer (score 2):

throw one array in a hash.  Look up the other array in the hash.  But that's not nlogn.. it's m+n.

Answer (score 1):

This approach does not need the `X` and `Y` to be sorted.

Add the elements of `X` to a binary search tree (avoid duplicate entries, i.e. if `X[0] = 1` and `X[1] = 1` then don't add `X[1]`; just ignore it).

Then try to add the contents of `Y` to the same binary search tree and If you find the element already in there, then its identical.

The total time complexity boils down to the time complexity of adding element to BST which is `O(n log n)` but worst case would be `O(n)` if the tree is skewed (i.e. if the arrays are sorted).

---

Here is the code for your reference!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
} NODE;

NODE *root = NULL;

NODE * newnode (int data)
{
        NODE * n = NULL;
        if (n = (NODE *) malloc (sizeof (NODE))) {
                n->data = data;
                n->right = n->left = NULL;
        } else {
                printf("%d - %d - unalbe to create new node \n", __LINE__, data);
        }

        return n;
}

NODE * getnode(NODE * n, int data)
{
        if (n == NULL)
                return NULL;

        if (n->data == data)
                return n;

        if (data < n->data)     {
                return getnode (n->left, data);
        }

        if (data > n->data) {
                return getnode (n->right, data);
        }

        return NULL;
}

NODE * insert (NODE * node, int data, int *dup)
{
    NODE * n = NULL;

    if (node != NULL) {
        if (getnode(node, data) != NULL) {
            /* element already present in the tree..
               so set the dup and return the root */
            *dup = 1;
            return node;
        }
    }

    if (node == NULL) {
        n = newnode(data);
        return (n);
    }

    if (data <= node->data)
        node->left = insert(node->left, data, dup);
    else
        node->right = insert(node->right, data, dup);

    return node;
}

NODE * deletetree(NODE * from)
{
    if (from != NULL) {
        deletetree(from->left);
        deletetree(from->right);
        //printf("deleting %d \n", from->data);
        free(from);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int sum = 35;
    int X[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5};
    int Y[] = {1,2,8,9};
    int i, dup = 0;

    int xlen = sizeof(X)/sizeof(X[0]);
    int ylen = sizeof(Y)/sizeof(Y[0]);

    printf("len of X is : %d \n", xlen);
    printf("len of Y is : %d \n", ylen);

    NODE * root1 = NULL;

    for (i=0; i<xlen; i++) {
        root = insert(root, X[i], &dup);
    }

    for (i=0; i<ylen; i++) {
        dup = 0;
        root = insert(root, Y[i], &dup);
        if (dup == 1) {
            printf("%d ", Y[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    root = deletetree(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so basically you say - dont sort just use binary search?  but binary search work only one sorted arrays ?

Comment: Adding n elements in a binary tree is O(nlogn). Though when you create binary tree you do not require sorting, but the complexity remains the same O(nlogn)

Comment: Sangeeth - if i cant use trees in this question how would you solve it?

Comment: @Shraddha Yes it is `O(nlogn)` i.e. `log n for adding` and `n for parsing the array`. My mistake. Corrected now.

Comment: @Alexxx If not `trees` then you can use `hash`. Same logic, if there is a collision when adding an entry ignore it for `X`.. but if collision happens when adding `Y` to the same `hash` then those are the identical values!

Comment: so you dont think that going with merge sort and binary search is a good idea? isnt that nlogn?

Comment: `merge sort` will sort the given arrays and when you create a binary search tree with sorted elements then it will be skewed which will end up in giving worst performance of `O(n)` during lookup instead of `O(log n)`. Imagine all the `left` elements of the tree is NULL and only `right` elements exist. It will behave like linked-list! (or) if you want the sorted elements to be inserted to the tree and still keep the tree balanced, then you should try some self balancing trees like `AVL` tree instead of `BST`

Comment: @Alexxx If you find the above answer satisfying, you can confirm it by clicking the tick mark next to it! .. Hope I have answered your question (with code).. Thanks!

Comment: i took 2 diffrent integer arrays.
i saved their sizes and checked who is bigger or smaller.
i sorted each one of the arrays using merge sort
and called a binary search function to search each one of the smallest array inside the bigger array.

is that nlogn
?

Comment: @Alexxx The above code that I have provided is `O(n log n)`. You don't need to sort the elements in this case. That is simply an overhead. Let me know if I can initiate a chat session on this topic if you need clarification!

Comment: @Alexxx If you find my answer satisfying, please feel free to confirm the same by clicking the tick mark next to it. Thanks!